# service broker behavior on target disabled

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

i need to know about behavior of sender service broker if target queue id disabled or unreachable . 
sender broker retry unlimited until lifetime and CPU is busy always ? Or can configure service broker sender for retry with schedule time (same replication)  . 
thanks  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retry occurs once per minute per destination (target address). Hierarchical flow control is specifically designed to minimize the impact on CPU even when a large number of messages is pending. You cannot configure the retry schedule. Service Broker is designed for contiguously connected systems with occasional unavailability.

Comment: thanks Remus . i want use service broker instead of replication (one publisher to many same subscription) . do you offer this solution ?

Comment: Replication has a lot of toolset around things like conflict resolution, replicating schema changes, re-seeding replicas, mointoring and troubleshooting and similar. Are you going to redo all those? What is the reason why you want to replace replication? And, last but not least, how do you plan to track data changes at the 'publisher'?